# NFSv4 is not added to rpc

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

I'm using Debian testing and although I've added NEED_IDMAPD="yes" to /etc/default/nfs-common.

My exports file is:

> /nfs4exports        192.168.10.0/24(ro,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,sync,root_squash)
>
> /nfs4exports/home   192.168.10.0/24(rw,nohide,sync,insecure,root_squash,no_subtree_check)

But rpcinfo -p only shows nfs version 2 and 3

> 100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
>
> 100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
>
> 100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
>
> 100003    3   udp   2049  nfs

This are dmesg related messages after restarting nfs-common and nfs-kernel-server:

> [1390754.762064] svc: 127.0.0.1, port=1016: unknown version (4 for prog 100003, nfsd)
> [1390756.912773] svc: 127.0.0.1, port=1017: unknown version (0 for prog 100003, nfsd)
> [1391147.296468] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
> [1391169.125568] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
> [1391301.401115] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
> [1391422.691600] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache

I've made sure that kernel has NFSv4 support (but not NFSv41) and I'm running it under arm architecture.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I miss read kernel config and it was compiled with NFSv4 client support but not server's. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I miss read kernel config and it was compiled with NFSv4 client support but not server

Comment: Glad you solved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.